# mysql display list of user defined functions in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, function

How can I view the list of user defined functions in mysql database using phpmyadmin.

Mysql database has been migrated from one server to another server and user defined custom functions are not working. I need to view the list of user defined function to check whether they exist in database or not.

```
Fatal error: db::execute() Could not execute: FUNCTION database.xxx does not exist (SQL: SELECT Function(field) FROM users in file.php on line xx
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? As of 5.1, the documentation says the information_schema.routines table does not contain user-defined functions. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/routines-table.html I'm confused.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The following MySQL query will list the user-defined routines.

```
select * from information_schema.routines;
```

Comment: Docs for 5.1 say the opposite of this. I'm confused. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/routines-table.html

Comment: It's the definition of "user-defined functions", that counts: Stored procs as declared in SQL are there, UDF's from an external engine (MySQL plugin in compiled form) are not.

Comment: What if I want to edit, say the name of the function. Is that possible?

Comment: You can't edit (in a strict sense of the word) a stored procedure at all - you can only replace it with an edited version, which is typically just as well. If you want to rename it, simply create a SP with the new name and the same defnition, then drop the old version.

Answer (score 4):

That will give you all the information about your custom functions/procedures:

```
select specific_name, definer from information_schema.routines where definer not like '%mysql%';
```

hope it helps!