# When using CREATE FUNCTION in MySQL, is the function persistent and where can I find it later?

Tags: mysql, function

When using `CREATE FUNCTION` I have a couple of basic questions:

- Is the function persistent? (Will it disappear if the server gets
  restarted?)
- If I need to look at a list of custom functions that are on the
  server at a later point, where do I go to do that? Is there a command
  like `SHOW FUNCTIONS`?

EDIT: First part of question is not addressed in link. Is the newly created function persistent?

Comment: related: http://serverfault.com/questions/51363/display-all-the-udfs-installed-on-a-mysql-server and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979285/mysql-display-list-of-user-defined-functions-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-function.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of Stored Procedures/Functions Mysql Command Line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733349/list-of-stored-procedures-functions-mysql-command-line)

Comment: @dan08 none of those address if it is persistent.

Comment: @kylex For user-defined functions the manual states: `An active function is one that has been loaded with CREATE FUNCTION and not removed with DROP FUNCTION. All active functions are reloaded each time the server starts [...]` Even though it's not explicitly stated for "normal" functions I would think it safe to assume that they persist just until dropped.